# Changing antibotlinks dependeing on site style

Tags: php, html

I have a crypto faucet and use antibotlinks to help with bots claiming. I also have an option where the users and choose between light/dark. The issue I have is the antibotlinks are hard to see in dark mode.

I know that if I change the abl_light_colors to on in the code below, they can be seen on dark mode, but not light.

```
var $abl_settings = array('abl_light_colors' => 'off', 'abl_background' => 'off', 'abl_noise' => 'on', 'abl_universe' => '');
```

My site changes the HTML tag of the site to determine the color of the site and this is the HTML tag of the site in dark mode

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" data-layout="horizontal" data-hor-style="hor-hover" data-position="scrollable" data-theme-color="dark">
```

Now, my question is, how can I have a php if and else statement that read the HTML tag of the site. I imaging it would be something that looks like this, but i'm not sure.

```
if (data-theme-color="dark")
var $abl_settings = array('abl_light_colors' => 'on', 'abl_background' => 'off', 'abl_noise' => 'on', 'abl_universe' => '');
else
var $abl_settings = array('abl_light_colors' => 'off', 'abl_background' => 'off', 'abl_noise' => 'on', 'abl_universe' => '');
```

I don't mean to sound stupid, but me and a few others are completely stumped on what to do.

Comment: When the user selects a link to change the theme, why not set a session variable to store their choice?

Comment: The themes js stores their selection in local storage, so when they visit again, it's the same as they selected.

Comment: So that `data-theme-color="dark"` on the `html` element does get set by client-side JavaScript? Then you can't get it using PHP.

Comment: What does changing this `abl_light_colors` value actually _do_? What about the actual final output created differs, to make those links show up in the color you want?

Comment: So if I have abl_light_colors on, then it draws in image with light font, if I set it to off. It draws the image with a dark font